# Doubts about General Relativity in Ashtekar variables and Thiemann trick - Perez "INTRODUCTION TO LOOP QUANTUM GRAVITY AND SPIN FOAMS"

Tags: general-relativity, poisson-brackets, loop-quantum-gravity

I am working on the Perez book, *INTRODUCTION TO LOOP QUANTUM GRAVITY AND SPIN FOAMS* (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0409061). In particular, I am interested in the understanding of the Poisson brackets (22)

$$
\{ E^{a}_{j}(x) , A^{i}_{b}(y) \} = \kappa \gamma \delta^{a}_{b} \delta^{i}_{j} \delta^{(3)}(x - y)
$$

and of the action (23)

$$
I = \dfrac{1}{\kappa} \int \mathrm{d}t \int_{\Sigma} \mathrm{d}^{3} x \bigg[ E^{a}_{i} \dot{A} \, ^{i}_{a} - \textit{ constraints } \bigg]
$$

where $\kappa = 8 \pi G$ and $\gamma$ is the Immirzi parameter. It seems to me that there is an inconsistency: if the Poisson brackets hold, one should have a pair $(A^{i}_{a}, E^{b}_{j})$ which reflects the same behaviour in the action coefficient. Then, one cannot use the same $E^{a}_{j}$ for both of these equations but one has to make the same distinction that Thiemann makes in his book, namely one introduces

$$
^{(\gamma)}{E}^{a}_{j} := E^{a}_{j}/\gamma .
$$

I am asking about this since I want to prove the Thiemann trick (133)

$$
K = \dfrac{1}{\gamma^{3/2}} \{ S^{E}(1) , V \}
$$

where $K$ is the integrated trace of the extrinsic curvature, $S^{E}(N)$ is the Euclidean part of the Hamiltonian constraint (in terms of $A^{i}_{b}$, $K^{i}_{b}$ and $E^{a}_{j}$) and $V = \int \sqrt{\det(E)}$ is the volume. I can get the factor $\gamma^{-3/2}$ only if I take the Euclidean term written by Perez (129) with $^{(\gamma)}{E}^{b}_{j}$ (instead of $E^{b}_{j}$) and then I compute the Poisson brackets for the Thiemann trick with respect to the pair ($A^{i}_{a}$, $^{(\gamma)}E^{b}_{j}$). Of course, in that case, the Poisson brackets would became

$$
\{\, ^{(\gamma)}E^{a}_{j}(x) , A^{i}_{b}(y) \} = \kappa \delta^{i}_{j} \delta^{a}_{b} \delta^{(3)}(x - y).
$$

I would really appreciate if someone could help me figuring out if I got it right.